# Is there a way to compare CGPoints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I would like something like this:

```
CGPoint a = CGPointMake(1, 1);
CGPoint b = CGPointMake(1, 1);

if ([CGHelperClass compareCGPoint:a to:b]){
  //do something
}
```

I know it's trivial to write yourself, but I'm curious if it's already there somewhere.

Comment: in swift: `if a == b { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**CGPointEqualToPoint**: Returns whether two points are equal.

```
bool CGPointEqualToPoint (
   CGPoint point1,
   CGPoint point2
);
```

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpointequaltopoint