# How to compare CGPoints In swift?

Tags: swift

I have 2 `CGPoint` like :

```
let a : CGPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)
let b : CGPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)
```

if Both are same then I want to do something.

This is just an example but I want to compare this two CGPoint and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363293/is-there-a-way-to-compare-cgpoints) question which is already asked but this is on objective-C so can anybudy tell me how can I do this is swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CGPoint` already implements the `Equatable` protocol, so you can compare using the `==` operator:

```
if a == b {
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. I recently had a bug where comparing two CGPoints wasn't working properly due to the precision, for instance, one y-coordinate was `16.666666666666742` while the other was `16.666666666666668` and that was failing the comparison. See this for further reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450259/705982

Answer (score 5):

Small example for you:

```
let a : CGPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)
let b : CGPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1)

if (a == b)
{
  var str = "YES"
}
```