# Comparing two CGPoints for equality: returning not equal for two objects that output same point?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335052/how-to-compare-cgpoints-in-swift), using == and != should let you check for equality between two `CGPoint` objects.

However, the code below fails to consider two `CGPoint` objects as equal even though they output the same value.

What is the right way to check equality among `CGPoint` objects?

**Code:**

```
    let boardTilePos = boardLayer.convert(boardTile.position, from: boardTile.parent!)
    let shapeTilePos = boardLayer.convert(tile.position, from: tile.parent!)   
    print("board tile pos: \(boardTilePos). active tile pos: \(shapeTilePos). true/false: \(shapeTilePos == boardTilePos)")
```

**Output:**

```
board tile pos: (175.0, 70.0). active tile pos: (175.0, 70.0). true/false: false
```

Comment: I think this has something to do with the inaccuracy of floating points...

Comment: @Sweeper so any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you can introduce like a threshold thing. If the difference between the two points does not exceed (+/-0.000001, +/-0.000001) then they are equal

Comment: @Crashalot just cast to an Int

Comment: Int(shapeTilePos.x) == Int(boardTilePos.x)

Comment: It has to do with what SpriteKit is doing behind the scenes,  just because you think it is 70.0, in reality it may be 70.00000000000001

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you then lose precision.  Points can have fractional x and y values...

Comment: @JAL see my answer,  I explain why I like to use Int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you see in the console is not what your real value is.

```
import UIKit

var x = CGPoint(x:175.0,y:70.0)
var y = CGPoint(x:175.0,y:70.00000000000001)

print("\(x.equalTo(y)), \(x == y),\(x),\(y)")
```

The problem is, the console only allows for 10<sup>-16</sup> but in reality your `CGFloat` can go even lower than that because on 64bit architecture, `CGFloat` is `Double`.

This means you have to cast your `CGPoint` values to a `Float` if you want to get equality that will appear on the console,  so you need to do something like:

```
if Float(boxA.x) == Float(boxB.x) && Float(boxA.y) == Float(boxB.y)
{
  //We have equality
}
```

Now I like to take it one step further.

In most cases,  we are using CGPoint to determine points on the scene.  Rarely do we ever want to be dealing with 1/2 points,  they make our lives just confusing.

So instead of `Float`,  I like to cast to `Int`.  This will guarantee if two points are lying on the same `CGPoint` in scene space

```
if Int(boxA.x) == Int(boxB.x) && Int(boxA.y) == Int(boxB.y)
{
  //We have equality
}
```

Comment: `Rarely do we ever want to be dealing with 1/2 points, they make our lives just confusing.` Right, like I said, you should technically be able to deal with fractional points.  This is more of a workaround, like calling `floor`.

Comment: We need to lose some kind of precision, because what Crashalot thinks is equal really isn't.

Comment: I did read your answer.  My argument still stands, if you're comparing 70 to 70.1, you answer equates them.  I'm just saying that's not always what everyone wants.

Comment: Yes, I understand how floating point numbers work.  You don't always have the luxury of logging points into a console and eyeballing if they're equal.  What if they're coming from a server or another device?

Comment: Look, I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm saying that in high precision scenarios (which I agree this situation isn't), you answer will lose precision.  You and I both know that, but some other user who wanders to this question from Google with a slightly different scenario won't.

Comment: @JAL, I am not sure what are you looking for here.  This answer is to a very specie problem.  Equality to what appears on the console for 2 positions on the screen.  This is not the end all be all of exact precession comparison between 2 points.  Sure we can subtract the 2 and use a valid range,  but in this case,  that type of comparison is not needed.

Comment: The idea is to lose precision to get to an equality,  this has to happen no matter what  because Apple tinkered with Crashalots frames by a teeny tiny smidgen,  a smidgen so small that he doesn't even know that it is happening.  How much precision is left up to the end user to decide.

Comment: @JAL this is a great discussion with KnightOfDragon. JAL is right that this answer is not the most precise, but KnightOfDragon is also right in making the correct trade-off ... but importantly, he also updated the answer to indicate this answer is not most precise so future readers will be protected. Thanks to both!

Comment: Precise is relative,  btw if you are going to do @JALs approach then I recommend making delta a computed property or the threshold equality an extension because you may end up in a situation where your precision on one class is off due to a typo

Answer (score 6):

I'm providing an alternate answer since I don't agree with Knight0fDragon's implementation.  This is only if you want to deal with factions of a point.  If you only care about points in whole numbers, see Knight0fDragon's answer.

You don't always have the luxury of logging points to the console, or seeing if you're trying to compare points that are the victim of floating point math, like comparing (175.0, 70.0) to (175.0, 70.00001) (which both log as (175.0, 70.0) in the console).  Yes, truncating to Int is a great way of understanding why two points that appear to print to the console as equal aren't.  But it's not a catch all solution one should use for comparing every point.  Depending on what level of precision you need, you want to take the absolute value of the difference of both x and y for each point, and see if it is in an acceptable range of a delta you specify.

```
var boxA = CGPoint(x:175.0, y:70.0)
var boxB = CGPoint(x:175.0, y:70.00000000000001)

let delta: CGFloat = 0.01

if (fabs(boxA.x - boxB.x) < delta) &&
   (fabs(boxA.y - boxB.y) < delta) {
    // equal enough for our needs
}
```

The answer to the question "What is the right way to check equality among `CGPoint` objects?" really depends on the way you compare floating point numbers.

Comment: You're right, @JAL. This is a more precise answer. Frustrating that `CGPoint` doesn't inherently provide a threshold parameter for equality.

Comment: @Crashalot a threshold does not make sense in regards to equality,  you are not trying to find if two values are equal, you are comparing if two values are below a threshold. It is not CGPoint that is the culprit, it is the Sprite Kit engine slightly modifying your position values.

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions and I agree with both :)

Answer (score -1):

CGPoint provides its own comparison method: `equalTo(_ point2: CGPoint)`

Try this:

```
shapeTilePos.equalTo(boardTilePos)
```

Comment: Does this mean the linked question is wrong? Thanks for sharing, didn't know about this function!

Comment: equalTo(_:)
Returns whether two points are equal.
Deprecated
The 
CGPoint
 type adopts the 
Equatable
 protocol; use the == operator instead.

Comment: Apple says do not use it

Comment: I actually tested this, and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks for testing this! could you post your comment as an answer? so far, your answer seems like the best option for testing equality.